# Pipes and prompts in Python CLI scripts

Tags: python, linux

Is it possible to combine piped input and TTY prompts in Python CLI scripts?  E.g., running this:

```
import sys

piped_text = None

if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    piped_text = sys.stdin.read()

user_in = raw_input('Enter something: ')

if piped_text:
    sys.stdout.write(piped_text)

sys.stdout.write(user_in + '\n')
```

Produces the following output:

```
~: python mrprompt.py
Enter something: something
something
~: echo foo | python mrprompt.py
Enter something: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mrprompt.py", line 9, in <module>
    user_in = raw_input('Enter something: ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

When the output I'm looking for is this:

```
~: python mrprompt.py
Enter something: something
something
~: echo foo | python mrprompt.py
Enter something: something
foo
something
```

I guess, worded differently, is it possible for a subshell to know the tty of its parent shell? Is it possible, in Python, to interact a parent shell's tty?  I use bash inside of GNU Screen (therefore, reading the 'SSH_TTY' environment variable is not a viable option).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works, more or less:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

saved_stdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty', 'r')
result = raw_input('Enter something: ')
sys.stdout.write('Got: ' + result + '\n')
sys.stdin = saved_stdin
result2 = sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdout.write('Also got: ' + result2)
```

Save as `foo.py` and try `echo goodbye | ./foo.py`

Of course, `/dev/tty` only exists on Unix.  And if you run it in a process with no controlling terminal, the `open()` will probably fail...

Comment: I think this should work on everything (common, at least) but Windows. Mac OS X has /dev/tty right?

Comment: @yam655 - I was thinking that OS X _is_ Unix as far as Python is concerned :-).  But you are right.

Comment: thanks!  Yes, this is the solution I was looking for.  For the time being, I'm only supporting Linux and it works fine on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

You can detect whether or not your `stdin` is coming from a pipe, as you are with `sys.stdin.isatty`.  You're getting the `EOF` because you read *all* the input from with the `stdin.read()` and then you try to read some more with the `raw_input()` command.

What you can't do is both pipe input and do inter-active input.  If you're piping input in, there is no other `stdin` for `raw_input` to work against.  The only `stdin` is the one coming from the file.

What you need to do is offer an optional way to have the appropriate part of your script read input from a file, with a switch like

```
--input=file.txt
```

and then provide interactive prompts for the other parts.

Comment: Other solution: do something like `cat file - | python mrprompt.py` if you want to get on stdin the content of `file` and then user input (there will be no separator between the two, however).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to accept both piped input and user input in the same program.

The easiest way to handle this is with the `subprocess` module. You would be executing the program from within your Python program. The arguments for it allow you to setup pipes to and/or from the program you are executing.

It is simple. It is standard. It works well.

The same is true for accepting a file through program arguments. It is simple. It is standard. It works well. As an added benefit, in Windows CMD.EXE/COMMAND.COM automatically uses temporary files for pipes. You get no benefit for doing anything more complicated due to DOS/Windows not supporting true pipes.

I know the command-line mysql client code accepts a password from the user before processing piped-in input. The Linux (and probably Mac OS X) solution to this is probably similar to what Nemo posted. If that's the behavior you really want, and you don't care about Windows, that's the solution to use. (For Windows, you'd need to use something like the wconio package. -- http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/wconio.html)

It *is* possible to have user-input and accept piped output going *to* another program. There are three standard file-handles: stdin, stdout, and stderr. You can write to stderr even when stdout is being redirected to a file.